# Yocto:How to use meta-intel to generate iso images that can be started in vmware?

Tags: yocto, iso

I want to use the meta intel layer to generate an ISO image of core image minimal.Although the image is generated normally, I cannot use vmware to start it. The picture is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRJYj.png)

This is my local.conf.

```
MACHINE  ?= "intel-corei7-64"
#
# This sets the default machine to be qemux86-64 if no other machine is selected:
MACHINE ??= "qemux86-64"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats"


IMAGE_FSTYPES += "live"
NOISO = "0"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-intel"

DEPENDS:append:${MACHINE} = " cdrtools-native"


IMAGE_FSTYPES:append = " ext4"
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_wic = "ext4"
do_image_wic[depends] += "${INITRD_IMAGE_LIVE}:do_image_complete"
do_rootfs[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_deploy"

IMAGE_BOOT_FILES:append = "\
  ${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE} \
  microcode.cpio \
  ${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_BASENAME}-${MACHINE}.ext4;rootfs.img \
  ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'grub-efi', 'grub-efi- bootx64.efi;EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi', '', d)} \
  ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'grub-efi', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg;EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg', '', d)} \
  ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', 'systemd-bootx64.efi;EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi', '', d)} \
  ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/loader/loader.conf;loader/loader.conf ', '', d)} \
  ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/loader/entries/boot.conf;loader/entries/boot.conf', '', d)} "
```

This is my bblayer.conf.

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/brain/poky/meta \
  /home/brain/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/brain/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/brain/poky/meta-intel\
  "
```

Now how can I generate an iso image that can be started normally？

Comment: I have the same problem, the image works in QEMU but not in VIrtualbox or VMware :/

Answer (score 0):

This one should work with VMWare:

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES = wic.vmdk
```

Comment: thanks very much，However, I still need to generate iso. Although the method of IMAGE__INSTALL+="iso" and IMAGE_FSTPES += " iso" can generate iso, it cannot be started on vmware and physical machines.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to boot the ISO on VirtualBox with following `local.conf` content:

```
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_wic = "ext4"
INITRD_IMAGE_LIVE="core-image-minimal-initramfs"
LABELS_LIVE = "boot install"
EFI_PROVIDER = "grub-efi" 
do_image_wic[depends] += "${INITRD_IMAGE_LIVE}:do_image_complete"
do_rootfs[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_deploy"
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES:append = "\
      ${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE} \
      microcode.cpio \
      ${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_BASENAME}-${MACHINE}.ext4;rootfs.img \
      ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'grub-efi', 'grub-efi-bootx64.efi;EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi', '', d)} \
      ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'grub-efi', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg;EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg', '', d)} \
      ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', 'systemd-bootx64.efi;EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi', '', d)} \
      ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/loader/loader.conf;loader/loader.conf ', '', d)} \
      ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/loader/entries/boot.conf;loader/entries/boot.conf', '', d)} "

INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
MACHINE_FEATURES_NATIVE:append = " efi"
MACHINE_FEATURES:append = " efi"
MACHINE_FEATURES:append = " pcbios util-linux-blkid"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " grub grub-efi grub-bootconf"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:append = " kernel-modules"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).